# Angular js cannot load data to my textare editor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, editor

I tried to load data to my normal textarea without using a directive it loads the data.But when i tried to use a directive so that my textare has editor on it , it does not load the data.

## text area with editor ( does not show the data )

```
 <textarea editor class="col-lg-12"  name="description" ng-model="main.record.basic_info.description" ></textarea>
```

## text area (this loads the data)

```
 <textarea rows="10" type="text"   name="description" ng-model="main.record.basic_info.description" class="form-control">
```

## editor directive

```
app.directive('editor', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).Editor();
    };
})
```

Comment: Are you referring to loading text onto the text area? That should be handled by ng-model using 2-way, right? You will need to use `require: 'ngModel'` in your directive

Comment: can you post an answer to that so i can upvote , thanks.

Comment: i did add ng model still the same

Comment: I shall give it another shot. Sorry, for being vauge, as I have not used Angular 1.x in a long while. For the past couple of years I have been using Angular 5-7. I will post the rest of the code on the answers.